# Firestore security rules: request.query.limit not working with compound query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```
 allow list: if request.query.limit <= 15;
```

This rule is simply ignored when used with compound query.

```
firestore().collection('orders').where('customerId', '==', uid)
      .where('orderStatusCode', 'in', [1, 2, 3])
      .limit(100)
      .get()....
```

Security rule:

```
  match /orders/{order} {
  allow list: if request.query.limit <= 15;

  allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.customerId;
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
  allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.customerId;
  allow delete: if false;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample query that ignores the rule? Also, having the entire security rule might be helpful to debug this issue.

Comment: What is the problem here? You have `limit <= 15` and your query is `limit(10)`, so you should be getting data. Are you not getting data?

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I will write up an answer now.

Comment: @dshukertjr I am getting data even when the limit is set 100 in query.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore security rules will allow the operation if any of the security rules allow the operation.

In your case, you are allowing `read` access in the line after the list rule. `read` is a combination of `get` and `list`. `get` is for document specific query, and `list` is for query on a collection. Even though the `list` rule was denied, `read` rule was passing, so your query was getting data.

You can update your security rule like this for it to work:

```
match /orders/{order} {
  allow list: if request.query.limit <= 15;

  allow get: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.customerId;
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
  allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.customerId;
  allow delete: if false;
}
```

Or, if you want to make data available to users where `auth.uid == customerId`, it would be like this:

```
match /orders/{order} {
  allow list: if request.query.limit <= 15 
  && request.auth.uid == resource.data.customerId;

  allow get: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.customerId;
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
  allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.customerId;
  allow delete: if false;
}
```